# Java return statement

Tags: java, return

Eclipse keeps telling me to add a return statement to the method, even though I did so.

```
public class PrefixCode { 
    public String isOne(String[] words) {
        if(words.length==1) {
            return "Yes";
        }
        ArrayList<Integer> indexPositions= new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i=0;i<words.length;i++) {
            String firstWord=words[i];
            java.util.List<String> listOfWordsToCheck = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(words));
            listOfWordsToCheck.set(i,null);
            for(int j=0;j<listOfWordsToCheck.size();j++) {
                String secondWord= listOfWordsToCheck.get(j);
                if(firstWord.startsWith(secondWord)==true) {
                    indexPositions.add(j);
                }
                else if(firstWord.startsWith(secondWord)==false);
            }
        }  
        if(indexPositions.size()==0) {
            return "Yes";
        }
        else if(indexPositions.size()!=0) {
            Collections.sort(indexPositions);
            return "No,"+indexPositions.get(0)+"";
        }
    }
}
```

My return statements are outside of the for loops, so I don't understand what's wrong here.

Comment: What happens if your `if` AND your `else if` conditions resolve to `false`? What is your method supposed to return in that case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no default return. The only returns you are making are `if` some conditions are true. What if the conditions are false?

<strike>Add a `return` after the last `else` block and you are all good to go.</strike>

The `else` block is redundant. What lies inside the `else` block should be be without `else`.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have added `if`, `else if`, you need to else to that control flow to satisfy the compiler. Logically, size can be either zero or more than zero. So, you need to have `if` and `else` part only

```
     if(indexPositions.size()==0){
         return "Yes";
     } else if(indexPositions.size()!=0){
        Collections.sort(indexPositions);
        return "No,"+indexPositions.get(0)+"";

     } else {
     // return what?
     }
```

You can simplify this logic by,

```
if(indexPositions.size() == 0) {
   return "Yes";
} else { //size more than zero
   Collections.sort(indexPositions);
   return "No,"+indexPositions.get(0) + "";
}
```

Comment: there is no 3rd option. just replace "else if" with "else"

Answer (score 2):

you should use `else` instead of

```
else if(indexPositions.size() != 0) {
    Collections.sort(indexPositions);
    return "No,"+indexPositions.get(0) + "";
}
```

Comment: Why use `else` block and why not a simple block?

Answer (score 1):

The compiler doesn't know if the `if` conditions are going to succeed. So, you need to add a default `return` out of those `if` (even if your `if` conditions cover all possible cases!)

Answer (score 0):

I usually do this by declaring a boolean at the start of the function and set it to false. If for whatever reason the function says that variable is gonna be true. I set the declared variable to true instead of returning true. At the end of the function i return that declared variable.

It then has its default return and if the variable was set to true, it returns true.

Answer (score 0):

One of the best practice is to have only one return at the method end! Like this:

```
public String isOne(String[] words) {
   String isOne = null;

   if(words.length==1){
      isOne = "Yes";
   }

   ...

   if(indexPositions.size()==0){
      isOne = "Yes";
   }
   else if(indexPositions.size()!=0){
     Collections.sort(indexPositions);
     isOne = "No,"+indexPositions.get(0)+"";
   }

   return isOne;
}
```

Sometimes you may initialize the variable with a default value too, even if in this case is not needed :

```
 String isOne = "No";
```

In also in your code there is an "error", the indexPositions.size may only be 0 or more, so you may want to use else instead of else if, and complete the graph. In this case eclipse won't tell you to add a return statement anymore, even if you use the return inside the condition block.

```
if(indexPositions.size()==0) {
  return "Yes";
}
else {
  Collections.sort(indexPositions);
  return "No,"+indexPositions.get(0)+"";
}
```